# Deploy an artifact to Artifactory as a bundle using REST api

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way to deploy an artifact as a bundle using Artifactory's rest api? I cant find it in the docs but seems unreasonable to enable only from the ui...

Comment: what do you mean by deploying an artifact as a bundle?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean bundle as in zip (archive) and deploy the zip and extract it in Artifactory rather than deploying each file, you can use [Deploy Artifacts from Archive](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/jfrog/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactsfromArchive) REST API.

If this isn't your use-case, kindly elaborate.